# Is there a way to make chrome load the previous website from cache instead of reloading it?

Tags: browser, website, browser-cache, refresh

In other words, is there a way to stop chrome from reloading the previous website on visit? I often click on a link, stay there for 10 and then hit the "back" button, which RELOADS the previous website (instead of taking it from cache), which is slow and annoying.

Comment: Whether it is possible depends on how the website has been programmed.

Comment: What I do is to click on the link with mouse's middle button, which opens the link in a new tab. I don't usually open a link in the same tab, unless I accidentally click on it when using a track-pad.

Answer (score 0):

Easy workaround would be to open the links in new tab, not navigate away from current page.

Comment: I do this, but sometimes it's not applicable (definitely more than 30% of the time)